# CSS Styling Disappeared

Tags: html, css, menu, styling

The menu works, so feel free to look at some of the pages and the weird styling issues.

I was styling the right-hand image on the first.php page, and I'm not sure if I added something extra or deleted something from my CSS. But now, my menu is listed in point form, rather than stylized as buttons and it has created a formatting mess on the website as well.

I can't seem to find what the problem is! Someone that understands code a bit better, please tell me what I'm missing :)

THE HTML..

AND THE CSS..

Why is my menu like this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you CSS check for your h3 element which has no closing tag "}"

To check for yourself:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options

Line 22, Column 16: Unclosed element div.

Line 8, Column 18: Unclosed element div

That should solve the formatted mess.

Comment: Check your h3 element. It has no closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

this fiddle shows the code. Its always good idea to properly indent code to show proper nesting so that tags can be properly managed.

```
 `http://jsfiddle.net/7KWQV`
```